# Operations defined on a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What does it mean for an operation to be defined on a set. Can interpret this as the binary operations allowed/needed to construct elements of a set?

Comment: An $n$-ary operation on a set $A$ is just a function $f\colon A^n\to A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A  binary operaion is a function that takes couples as inputs.
- Saying that it is defined on a set  S means that

a) it only takes as inputs couples belonging to $S\times S$ ( the cartesian product of S by itself)

b) and only sends back as outputs elements of S.

- For example substraction is not a binary operation on $N $ ( the set of natural numbers) , since , for example, when it takes the couple $ (4,7)$, it sends back $-3$ which is not an element of $N$.
- In general an n-ary operation on a set $S$ is a function that takes n-tuples belonging to $S\times S \times S $ ... ($n$ times) as inputs and sends back elements of $S$ as outputs.